# Error en estructuras

Tags: c

soy nuevo en programación y me apareció un error el cual no puedo encontrar una solución.
El error especificamente se indica en ambos For, con lo cual pienso que puede ser una mala indicacion de la estructura, aunque intente cambiar todas las formas de indicar la estructura anidada sigue apareciendo el error.

error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
en la linea: sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct piscinas{
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
}piscinas[20];
typedef struct galpones{
    struct piscinas datos_piscina;
}galpones[5];
typedef struct sucursales{
    struct galpones datos_galpon;
}sucursales[3];



int main()
{
    int aux_sucursal, aux_galpon, pis, i;
    do{
    printf("Indique la sucursal a la cual quiere acceder \n");
    scanf("%i", &aux_sucursal);
    } while (aux_sucursal<1 || aux_sucursal>3);
    do{
    printf("Indique al galpon al cual quiere acceder \n");
    scanf("%i", &aux_galpon);
    } while (aux_sucursal<1 || aux_sucursal>5);
    do{
    printf("Indique la cantidad de piscinas \n");
    printf("Minimo cantidad de piscinas: 2 \n");
    printf("Maxima cantidad de piscinas: 20 \n");
    scanf("%i", &pis);
    } while (pis<2);

    aux_galpon=aux_galpon-1;
    aux_sucursal=aux_sucursal-1;

    for(i=0; i<pis; i++){
        sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100;
        sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].corriente= rand() %201+150;
        sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].voltaje = 2;
    }
    for(i=0; i<pis; i++){
            printf("\nDATOS DE LA PISCINA %i \n", i+1);
            printf("Temperatura : %i \n",sucursales[aux_sucursal-1].datos_galpon[aux_galpon-1].datos_piscina[i].temperatura);
            printf("corriente   : %i \n",sucursales[aux_sucursal-1].datos_galpon[aux_galpon-1].datos_piscina[i].corriente);
            printf("voltaje     : %i \n",sucursales[aux_sucursal-1].datos_galpon[aux_galpon-1].datos_piscina[i].voltaje);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cuando defines una estructura así:

```c
typedef struct piscinas{
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
}piscinas;
```

Con el `typdef` indicas que estás creando un alias llamado `piscinas` de `struct piscinas`. Es mas, este seria el código equivalente:

```c
//Declara la estructura.
typedef struct piscinas piscinas; // "piscinas" es un alias de "struct piscinas".

//Define la estructura.
struct piscinas{
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
};
```

Volviendo a tu código:

```c
typedef struct piscinas{
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
}piscinas[20];
```

Está claro que ahí **NO estás creando un array de estructuras de 20 elementos**. Más bien, estás creando un alias llamado `piscinas` de `struct piscinas[20]`. Como verás, en C es posible crear un alias a un *array* (que es un tipo complejo).

Por lo que ahora puedes declarar un array de estructuras de esta manera:

```c
piscinas pis1;
piscinas pis2;
```

**Otros ejemplos:**

```c
typedef int vector_t[20];
vector_t vector1; // Es equivalente a "int vector1[20]"

typedef char name_t[24];
name_t primerNombre; // Es equivalente a "char primerNombre[24]"
```

Para que no se confunda, no defina un alias, hágalo así:

```c
typedef struct piscinas{
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
}piscinas;

//Luego declare el *array*:
piscinas pis1[20];
```

> > error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token en la linea: sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100;

El motivo del error es porque `sucursales` no es un array de estructuras, sino, un **alias de tipo**, es de decir, `sucursales` es un alias de `struct sucursales[20]`, no lo puedes utilizar como si fuera una variable (tal como lo ha dicho Pablochaches). Con el alias `sucursales` puedes declarar variables que representen a un array de estructuras.

Para corregir el error, debe declarar una variable de tipo `sucursales` al principio del `main`:

```c
sucursales arraySuc;
```

Y luego lo podrás usar de esta manera:

```c
arraySuc[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100
```

Y el error de compilación debería desaparecer.

### Solución (2)

Sin embargo, le propongo otra solución más simple:

```c
typedef struct piscinas{
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
}piscinas;

typedef struct galpones{
    piscinas datos_piscina[20]; // Declaramos el array de estructuras.
}galpones;

typedef struct sucursales{
    galpones datos_galpon[5];  // Declaramos el array de estructuras.
}sucursales;

sucursales datos_sucursales[3];  // Declaramos el array de estructuras.
```

**Nota:** Como `galpones` es un alias de `struct galpones` no necesitamos anteponer la palabra `struct` al declarar una variable de un tipo de estructura.

Luego puedes utilizar la "variable" de esta manera:

```c
datos_sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100
```

También puede utilizar **estructuras anónimas**:

```c
typedef struct { // --> no hace falta volver a especificar "piscinas".
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
}piscinas;

typedef struct { // --> no hace falta volver a especificar "galpones".
    piscinas datos_piscina[20];
}galpones;

typedef struct { // --> no hace falta volver a especificar "sucursales".
    galpones datos_galpon[5];
}sucursales;

sucursales datos_sucursales[3];
```

Use la solución que le parezca más fácil de entender. Si va a crear *alias de tipo*, trate de usar nombres más significativos, algo como:

```c
SucursalArray surcusales1;
PiscinaArray piscinas1;
```

Comment: @Pablochaches Como está pablito..... jeje ya ando medio oxidado, C# me tiene así (? ... he corregido la respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, borro el comentario para no llenar la caja con cosas irrelevantes. Buenisima la respuesta, bien completa.

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate en como estas declarando las estructuras:

```c
typedef struct sucursales{
    struct galpones datos_galpon;
}sucursales[3];
```

Por el uso que le das mas abajo, supongo que entiendes que el resultado de esto
no es crear un array de `struct sucursales`, sino que al tipo *"un array de
3 elementos de `struct sucursales`"* le das el nombre de `sucursales`. (Mas
detalles
[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array/4523537))

De ser esa tu intención, hay 2 errores:

Primero, usar los nombres completos dentro de los structs:

```
typedef struct piscinas {
  float temperatura;
  float voltaje;
  float corriente;
} piscinas[20];
typedef struct galpones {
  piscinas datos_piscina; // struct piscinas -> piscinas
} galpones[5];
typedef struct sucursales {
  galpones datos_galpon; // struct galpones -> galpones
} sucursales[3];
```

Y segundo, no crear una variable que usar (recuerda que `sucursales` en este
caso es un tipo y tu lo usas como variable). Esta es la fuente de el error:

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token en la linea: sucursales[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100;
```

La solucion a esto es sencilla, crear una variable de tipo `sucursales`,
colocarla en los lugares donde uses `sucursales` como una variable (En mi
correccion usare `suc` como nombre, tu pon el que quieras).

Corrigiendo el código, te quedaría como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct piscinas {
    float temperatura;
    float voltaje;
    float corriente;
} piscinas[20];
typedef struct galpones {
    piscinas datos_piscina;
} galpones[5];
typedef struct sucursales {
    galpones datos_galpon;
} sucursales[3];

int main() {
    sucursales suc;
    int        aux_sucursal, aux_galpon, pis, i;
    do {
        printf("Indique la sucursal a la cual quiere acceder \n");
        scanf("%i", &aux_sucursal);
    } while (aux_sucursal < 1 || aux_sucursal > 3);
    do {
        printf("Indique al galpon al cual quiere acceder \n");
        scanf("%i", &aux_galpon);
    } while (aux_sucursal < 1 || aux_sucursal > 5);
    do {
        printf("Indique la cantidad de piscinas \n");
        printf("Minimo cantidad de piscinas: 2 \n");
        printf("Maxima cantidad de piscinas: 20 \n");
        scanf("%i", &pis);
    } while (pis < 2);

    aux_galpon = aux_galpon - 1;
    aux_sucursal = aux_sucursal - 1;

    for(i=0; i<pis; i++){
        suc[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].temperatura=rand()%100;
        suc[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].corriente= rand() %201+150;
        suc[aux_sucursal].datos_galpon[aux_galpon].datos_piscina[i].voltaje = 2;
    }

    for(i=0; i<pis; i++){
            printf("\nDATOS DE LA PISCINA %i \n", i+1);
            printf("Temperatura : %i \n",suc[aux_sucursal-1].datos_galpon[aux_galpon-1].datos_piscina[i].temperatura);
            printf("corriente   : %i \n",suc[aux_sucursal-1].datos_galpon[aux_galpon-1].datos_piscina[i].corriente);
            printf("voltaje     : %i \n",suc[aux_sucursal-1].datos_galpon[aux_galpon-1].datos_piscina[i].voltaje);
    }
    return 0;
}
```